# Camera switching script for 8 directional cameras?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

Im new to coding and am tying to figure out my a camera swapping script. I have 8 Cinemachine virtual cameras positioned around the player in 45 degree increments around the Y-axis for each direction(N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW). My plan is to use "Q" and "E" keys to transition through each camera to create a full rotation around the player but with the fixed perspective of the 8 cameras.

I have my 8 cameras set up in the State Drive and animator. I want "Q" to loop through the cameras to create a counterclockwise rotation around the player and "E" to be clockwise.

[[image: List of Cameras]
[image: Animator]
[image: Cameras in Scene]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Cinemachine`, you are definitely familiar with the `State Driven Camera`. This feature can switch virtual cameras via an `Animator`. For example, after creating a state driven from the `Cinemachine` menu, I put three virtual cameras with the following names in it and adjusted each one to the desired angles.

[image]

---

### Cinemachine State Driven Camera Setup

At the bottom, you will see the `State Driver Camera` component, to activate virtual cameras, create an animator and place it in Animated Target. This camera automatically detects animator states and moves the cameras according to changing states:

[image]

I set the animator as shown below and set the names of the states as well as the parameters to make it easier.

[image] [image]

---

### Switching Camera Script

Finally, using the code below, refer the keys to change the parameter and you can see the change of cameras.

```cs
public Animator stateDrivenAnimator; // fill state driven animator here

public List<KeyCode> KeyCodes = new List<KeyCode>() // some keys for example
{
    KeyCode.Q,
    KeyCode.W,
    KeyCode.E
};
public void Update()
{
    KeyCodes.ForEach(k => { if (Input.GetKeyDown(k)) stateDrivenAnimator.SetTrigger(k.ToString()); });
}
```

---

### Rotate clockwise and counterclockwise

For this purpose, it is better to define the camera rotation process in the `Index`. It is enough to define only one `Index` parameter instead of `Triggers` and condition every state by rotation cycle in order like the image.

- (N == 0)
- (NE == 1)
- (E == 2)
- (SE == 3)
- (S == 4)
- (SW == 5)
- (W == 6)
- (NW == 7)

[image]
[image]

Finally, the bottom code rotates the Index in the loop with `CW` and `CCW` keys instead of placing the key letters in the `Trigger`, and the cameras are set according to the Index.

```cs
public CinemachineStateDrivenCamera stateDriven; // Get state-drive here

public KeyCode CW;
public KeyCode CCW;

private int index;

public void Update()
{
    if (!Input.GetKeyDown(CW) && !Input.GetKeyDown(CCW)) return;
    var animator = stateDriven.m_AnimatedTarget;
    var childCount = stateDriven.transform.childCount;
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(CW)) index = ++index % childCount;
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(CCW)) index = (index == 0) ? childCount - 1 : --index;
    
    animator.SetInteger("Index", index);
}
```

Comment: thank you!! this is extremely helpful :3 I got all the states set up but the script still isn't quite what i was looking to do. I want to use just two keys to cycle back and forth through all cameras. For example pressing "E" will loop one direction though all cameras and pressing "Q" will loop through the other direction. Using your comment as an example, pressing "E" will loop from cam Q to W then to E and back to Q, while pressing "Q" will loop from cam Q to E then to W and back to Q.

Comment: Glad if it was helpful. If `stateDriven` was successful, only you need code improvement's. Since your question has long answer, I preferred to go into generalities as much as possible. If you refer to a video from YouTube, it will be very easy to understand what you want. As far as I understand until now, you want to rotate between 8 cameras with two keys. The cameras are arranged like a numpad and you want to rotate around number 5 with E, Q.

Comment: I rephrased my question to hopefully clarify my question. Im trying to mimic a 360 rotation around my player by transitioning between cameras at fixed positions around the player.

Comment: @naturalcrybaby I improved the answer. The method you need to do this is to rotate the Index.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was trying to do. I got everything to work but the cameras are not displaying when activated. The view is stuck on the main cameras view. I can see the cameras being rotated in the scene editor but the game view its only displaying the main camera. *Edit* It was the main cameras priority, it was still set to 10 so it was overriding the others. I got it to work now thank you!

Comment: Glad you were able to run it. ;) I hope this post is useful for others as well.